# Do .pyc files contain type hinting information?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, pyc

I assumed standard library type hinting support was all based on reading the plain source like `inspect` does for some things, but I looked at [typing.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/97b523db7c79c18c48516fba9410014d9896abc4/Lib/typing.py#L926) in the standard library and it seems the compiler does store type hint info on the object itself.

So, if I do:

```
def myfunc(a: int, b:int): -> str
    return "{a} + {b} = {a+b}"
```

and then compile that to a .pyc file, does the type information stick around such that someone who I've given the .pyc file can use things like `typing.get_type_hints()` to access it? (With the assumption that I have a valid reason to distribute just the .pyc.)

Comment: You can simply test that by creating a `.pyc` file from your python file and then importing the compiled module and testing it by yourself.

Comment: @Kasramvd Sure, but I wanted there to be a StackOverflow question for this. :P

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have answered your own question

Comment: @barny Self-answered questions aren't off-topic, although the OP should actually post an answer of their own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I have just impersonated your `someone` here :) with your code and the answer is yes it works, after I changed the
`def myfunc(a: int, b:int): -> str` to

```
def myfunc(a: int, b:int) -> str:
```

otherwise it's a syntax error.

Comment: While, humorous, this doesn't really answer the question further than "yes" and should just be an edit to the original question.

Comment: @ethanhs You mean could be just a comment. I wouldn't edit this kind of change in someone else's question, invalidating it. I considered the comment, but it would be like "why don't you try yourself" (I don't like much that kind of comments, could be read as despise), so I didn't. Also because I actually didn't know the answer too, (to comment yes) until I tested. So the question is yes/no, answer is yes I tested it. I see also your point of not having some elaboration about, but it looks there's nothing special to elaborate on (see "obvious behaviour" in Kasramvd answer)

Comment: Of course reviewing `typing.py` code would have been better as the answer tested a single case.

Comment: I saw the question as, and I think it would be a more valuable question to ask: "Do .pyc files contain type hinting information?". The specific example is syntactically incorrect and in my eyes an error in asking the question, not part of the question itself. It would be silly to ask if an incorrect program stores information in the bytecode, as it would never reach that stage.

Answer (score 3):

You already answered your question here:

*but I looked at typing.py in the standard library and it seems the compiler does store type hint info on the object itself.*

This means that typing information doesn't get lost and gets compiled with the rest of your code which is an obvious behavior. You can simply test that by creating a `.pyc` file from your python file and then importing the compiled module and testing it as following. Also note that you have a syntax error in your code. You should move the `:` after `-> str`:

```
In [38]: import py_compile

In [39]: py_compile.compile('ex.py')
Out[39]: '__pycache__/ex.cpython-35.pyc'

In [40]: cd __pycache__/
/home/kasra/Desktop/__pycache__

In [41]: import ex

In [42]: ex.myfunc
Out[42]: <function ex.myfunc(a:int, b:int) -> str>

In [43]: import typing

In [44]: typing.get_type_hints(ex.myfunc)
Out[44]: {'a': int, 'b': int, 'return': str}
```